# Get last 3 added products from cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, mini-cart

How can i get last 3 added products of cart in magento.

I am using `$session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems()` for that.

Please Provide me if any other feasible solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find answer by looking at `getRecentItems` method inside `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar` class.

```
/**
 * Get array of last added items
 *
 * @param null $count
 * @return array
 */
public function getRecentItems($count = null)
{
    if (!$this->getSummaryCount()) {
        return array();
    }
    if ($count === null) {
        $count = $this->getItemCount();
    }
    return array_slice(array_reverse($this->getItems()), 0, $count);
}
```

This applies to current customer session.

Comment: Can You Explain it how can i use i am new in magento.

Comment: @Yogesh It really depends what you want to do with these three products.

Comment: Thanks For Reply Actaully i am using this $session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() and it gives me all product array so i just need last 3 products

Answer (score 2):

You could just iterate through the items and stop after 3.

```
$product_ids = array();
$i=0;
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $i++;
    if ($i==4) break;
    $product_ids[] = $item->getProduct()->getId();
}

var_dump($product_ids);
```

Comment: You should use getAllVisibleItems().

Comment: Yes for sure.  I missed that.  I like your answer better  about referring to the `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar` class.